# I want to calculate mode, median, and Standard Deviation of the data in javascript

Tags: javascript, mean, median, mode

I want to calculate the Standard Deviation of the data, mode, and median so I was wondering if someone could help me out with these functions?

I've tried calling math.js but it doesn't work.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/stats-lite

```
   //
   // function myFunction(){
   //      alert("Hello Javatpoint");
   //
   // }
   //
   //  function myFunction2(){
   //      alert("Hello Nasser ");
   //
   // }

   function mean(values){

     var total = 0,
        i, results;
     var onlyNumbers = values.replace(/\D/g, '');
        for (i = 0; i < onlyNumbers.length; i += 1) {
            total += parseInt(onlyNumbers[i]);
        }
    results = total / onlyNumbers.length;
    document.getElementById("meanOutput").innerHTML = results;


   }

   function mode() {
        document.getElementById("modeOutput").innerHTML = "Fahad!";
   }

   function median() {
        document.getElementById("medianOutput").innerHTML = "Nasser";

   }

   function stdv() {
        document.getElementById("stdvOutput").innerHTML = "Alqahtani";
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

<body>

    Mean: <input type="text"
    id="meanText" >
    Median:<input type="text"
    id="medianText" >
    Mode:<input type="text"
    id="ModeText" >
    Standard Deviation of the data:<input type="text"
    id="STDV" >

    <p id="meanOutput"></p>
    <p id="modeOutput"></p>
    <p id="medianOutput"></p>
    <p id="stdvOutput"></p>



    <button onclick="mean(document.getElementById('meanText').value); median(); mode(); stdv();">Calculate</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect to see correct results for median, mode and Standard Deviation of the data.

Comment: Hi! Can you update your snippet with the code you wrote for calculating the mode, median, and standard deviation?

Comment: Can you give more details about why mathjs does not work

Comment: This's the updated one since I used the codes here https://www.npmjs.com/package/stats-lite and delete it. I installed it and it doesn't work, the result it gives me for median function for example is NaN

Comment: Your code basically just sets mode and median to Fahad and Nasser. Where's the actual code for getting the mode/median? https://www.mathsisfun.com/mode.html https://www.mathsisfun.com/median.html https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation-formulas.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57779594/im-stuck-with-calculating-mode-median-standard-deviation-of-the-data This's a new question I posted, and I know the formula but how I can transform them into javascript. Finally, ignore Fahad and Nasser.

Comment: And it would be great if you could show us what you've come up with so far :)

Answer (score 0):

is this my calculate mode way, i used a condicional if whole numbers of array is differens then return the Math.min:

```js
var arrayP = [4,2,3,6,1,10] // example array 
console.log(Mode(arrayP)) // example result

// function calculate mode 
const Mode = arr =>{
  var uniques = Array.from(new Set(arr)).map(r=>[r,0])
  if (uniques.length == arr.length){return Math.min(...arr)}
  for(q in arr){
    for(j in uniques){
        if(arr[q] == uniques[j][0]){
        uniques[j][1] += 1
      }
    }
  }
  uniques.sort((a,b)=> b[1]-a[1])
  return uniques[0][0]
}
```